# You can find out if a list is a palindrome using (==) <*> reverse. How does it work?

Tags: list, haskell, reverse, palindrome

I've tried to go through this using the types, but I'm still having difficulty understanding how it works.

Given:

```
> :t (==)
(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool

> :t (<*>)
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

> :t reverse
reverse :: [a] -> [a]

> :t (==) <*> reverse
(==) <*> reverse :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
```

Intuitively I can understand that it combines the equality operator with reverse in such a way that it creates a function that checks if a reversed list is equal to the original, but that's really not much more information than what is already pretty obvious.

Could someone break down in more detail the internals of what is actually happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chris Taylor's answer is just right, but another way of looking at it, that I find more intuitive, is this: what the `Applicative` instance of function types does is this:

1. "Feed" the same argument value to two functions with the same argument type;
2. Combine their results with another function.

So basically, if you have `f :: t -> a` and `g:: t -> b`, the `Applicative` instance lets you map functions `h :: a -> b -> c` over the `a` and `b` results, under the assumption that `f` and `g` will be fed the same argument.

So think of how you'd write the palindrome test in a non-convoluted way:

```
palindrome :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
palindrome xs = xs == reverse xs
```

`xs` appears twice on the right hand side of the definition: once as argument to `==`, and a second time as argument to `reverse`.  This automatically tells you that there is likely a way to use the `(->) t` applicative instance to eliminate the duplication.  A different, perhaps more intuitive attack on this would be to first rewrite the function to this:

```
palindrome xs = id xs == reverse xs
```

...where `id x = x` is the *identity function*, which just returns its argument (and is a standard library function).  Now you can rewrite that using the standard `Applicative` idiom (`f <$> a0 <*> ... <*> an`) to this:

```
-- Function that feed the same argument value to both `id` and `reverse`,
-- then tests their results with `==`: 
palindrome = (==) <$> id <*> reverse
```

And now we can ask if there is a way to get rid of `id` in that rewrite.  Since `<$>` is just shorthand for `fmap`, we can study the `Functor` instance for `(->) t`, which is just another way to express function composition:

```
instance Functor ((->) t) where
  -- Mapping `f` over a *function* `g` is just the same as composing `f`
  -- on the results of `g`.
  fmap f g = f . g
```

One of the most important properties of function composition is that for any function `f`:

```
f . id = f
```

So applying that to the version of `palindrome` above, we get:

```
-- Since `f . id = f` for all `f`, then `(==) <$> id` is just `(==)`:
palindrome = (==) <*> reverse
```

Comment: Why do you always have to come up with the nice, clear answers?

Comment: Coming back to it two months later is made so much more sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Start with the type of `(<*>)`

```
> : t (<*>)
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Now `(->) k` is an instance of `Applicative`, with implementation

```
instance Applicative ((->) k) where
    pure a  = \_ -> a
    f <*> g = \k -> f k (g k)
```

In particular, the type of `(<*>)` specialised to `(->) k` is

```
(<*>) :: (k -> a -> b) -> (k -> a) -> (k -> b)
```

So the application `(==) <*> reverse` is

```
(==) <*> reverse = \k -> (==) k (reverse k)
                 = \k -> k == reverse k
```

i.e. it checks that a list is equal to its reverse.

Comment: What do you mean by `(->) k` is that a lambda?

Comment: Some background: `((->) t)` is "a function taking a `t` as input", and in your case `t` is `String`. The Applicative instance for that receives a `String`, and passes it to the first function `f`, getting back another function `f'`. It passes *that same String* to the second function, getting back a value of some kind; and then it calls `f'` with the returned value. Hence `(f <*> g) x == f x (g x)`.

Comment: @amalloy I think a lot of my confusion comes from how the type signature of `<*>` changes. For example how `f (a -> b)` became `(k -> a -> b)`. Why is this the case for `(->) k`?

Comment: Its type signature doesn't change, but rather we use a more specialized version of it. `<*>` works for any Applicative, just like `==` works for any Eq. `(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`, and in our case `f :: ((->) String)`. So we substitute for `f`, and arrive at `(<*>) :: (String -> a -> b) -> (String -> a) -> (String -> b)`. Further, `a :: String` and `b :: Bool`, so `(<*>) :: (String -> String -> Bool) -> (String -> String) -> (String -> Bool)`. Finally, remove the extraneous `()`, to get `(<*>) :: (String -> String -> Bool) -> (String -> String) -> String -> Bool`.